# using require without vue CLI, just vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to put my template code into another file, I cannot use vue CLI, I'm just using a simple version of vue.

This does not work

```
  Vue.component('header-app', {
    template: require('./components/header.html')
  })
```

Where as this does work

```
Vue.component('header-app', {
template: ` <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>`
})
```

But my template code will be very big, so better to put into separate files.

I've been reading forums etc but still no real answer, remember, I cannot use Vue Cli, just vue.js

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? You should look at [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: @mbuechmann how to put template code into another file and call that file in Vue.component?

Comment: Use XHR to load the external file into a string. Then run the result with `Vue.component`.